# Remove Byte Order Mark (BOM)

Tags: gvim, text-editing

### Background

Run SQL files using `pgsql` that were edited with gVim on Windows.

### Problem

The BOM character causes syntax errors with `pgsql`. I would like to edit files using gVim and, when saved, no longer have a BOM character. If the file has the BOM character, then saving it keeps the BOM character, which is not desired.

### Ideas

Changed the settings (**Edit » Startup Settings**) as follows:

```
set nocompatible
source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/mswin.vim
behave mswin
au BufReadPre set nobomb
au BufReadPre setlocal nobomb
au BufReadPre setglobal nobomb
au BufReadPost set nobomb 
au BufReadPost setlocal nobomb 
au BufReadPost setglobal nobomb 
au BufWritePre set nobomb
au BufWritePre setlocal nobomb
au BufWritePre setglobal nobomb
au BufWritePost set nobomb
au BufWritePost setlocal nobomb
au BufWritePost setglobal nobomb
set encoding=utf-8 nobomb    " BOM often causes trouble
setlocal nobomb
setglobal nobomb
```

Didn't work. I still have to type `:set nobomb` to explicitly remove the BOM.

### Question

How do you configure gVim so that the BOM is stripped immediately upon loading the file, without having to remember to type `:set nobomb` every time? (I want to set it and forget it.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
au BufWritePre set nobomb
```

Comment: `au BufWritePre * setlocal nobomb`, you need to honor the `{pat}` argument (which is 'set' in dennis' example)...

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your *.vimrc*:

```
au BufWritePre * setlocal nobomb
```

*(Taken from a comment to another answer as this is actually a better solution.)*

Comment: @zagrimsan The other solution is a bit different. An identical solution is posted as a comment rather as an answer. Personally, when I come to a thread, I would like to see a proper answer that I can use without having to read all the comments. This answer is just it. I guess you wanted to down-vote me, but instead you have down-voted the best answer in this thread.